# Suggested edit approved twice?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

According to [this revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23703515/revisions), there was [this suggested-edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1339580) that got approved twice.

I've double-checked with [the user's reputation-history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2249026/tod?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=3), and he got awarded +2 twice for that edit:

[image]

Note also that the edit from **tod** was approved by a different **Tod**.

Comment: The two tod's are not related.

Comment: According to [the public data dump](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/719030), this has happened 325 times, most recently in June - that last one is particularly notable because there was a separate edit made between the two applications of the edit, which was then lost when the edit was applied a second time!

Comment: @Shog9 oh, the lost edit actually happened to all three double approvals of 2017.