# Ghost revision on same-second edit/approval

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, revision-history

Earlier today I Improve edited [an suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18113752) that already had one "approve" vote. Coincidentally another reviewer approved the same suggested edit the very same second as my edit.

This caused some strange behavior: The suggested edit now appears twice [in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47576670/revisions), with my edit in between. (Both "edit approved" links point to the same suggested edit.) The last one appears to undo my improvements.

[image: Suggested edit applied two times with my edit in between]

If I look at the post itself it *does* show me as the last editor, as well as my improvements to the post:

[image: The Post with my edit as latest]

Though when I click on the edit button, it shows the source with the latest revision i.e. without my improvements.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356159/suggested-edit-approved-twice